# How to defer parsing barebone javascript in liferay (if possible)

Tags: javascript, performance, liferay, pagespeed

I am trying to optimize my portal performance using pagespeedz. There is one issue that I can't resolve:

```
Defer parsing of JavaScript
108.7KiB of JavaScript is parsed during initial page load. Defer parsing JavaScript to     reduce blocking of page rendering.

http://www.inap.es/html/js/barebone.jsp?browserId=other&themeId=inap2013theme_WAR_inap2013theme&colorSchemeId=01&minifierType=js&minifierBundleId=javascript.barebone.files&languageId=es_ES&b=6012&t=1384420209000
```

All the information I've found is related to how to compress this javascript, but I can't find any on how to defer it's parsing. I am wondering if maybe deferring it is a bad idea, since I assume it has a lot of packed javascript that could be needed to correctly visualize my page. I would like to try it and be sure anyway.

Thanks, regards

Comment: If the JavaScript is needed to render the page, then you can't really help it. But usually you have things like click handlers and page interactions which can be loaded later on.